# Bootstrap Modal: Can't click button for a second time after clicking other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

We have a modal showing and inside the modal we have a `noShow` button and an input field that's associated to a `walkOn` button. The show button doesn't work after there has been a call to `walkOn` button.

What is wrong and how can we fix it?

```
function getModalData(mon) {
  $('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click',function() {

    //walkOnUrl is prepared

   if (modalId == '#otherShift') {
      $('#otherShiftText').load(dataURL,function() {

        $('#otherShift').modal('show');
```

Here is the part with the `noShow` button which works if it's called once or  however many times as long as there is no calls to walk  on in between.

```
        $(".noShow").on("click", function(){
          var url = $(this).attr("href");
          var noShowNetID = $(this).attr("netid").trim();
          var noShowArea = '\"#noshow'  + noShowNetID + '\"';
          $(this).parent("span").load(url);
        });
```

Here is the event listener associate with the `walkOnSubmit` button.

```
        $("#walkOnSubmit").on("click", function() {
          var walkOnNetId = $("#walkOnInput").val();
          $("#walkOnText").text('');
          walkOnUrl += "&netid=" + walkOnNetId;
          console.log($('#otherShiftText').html());
          $.ajax({
            url: walkOnUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
              if (data == "failed") {
                $("#walkOnText").html("<br><br>walkOn Request Failed. Please try again.");
                $("#walkOnInput").val('');
              }
              else {
                console.log(data)
                curr = $('#otherShiftText').html() + data;
                // console.log(curr);
                $('#otherShiftText').html(curr);
                $("#walkOn").val('');
              }
            }
          });
        });
  }
});

}
```

Note: The parentheses might be wrong since I took irrelevant parts of the code out. I don't think that's the issue with the code.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code, including your modal, you are sharing it in chunks so it is hard to tell if thesequence of code makes sense.

Comment: Please provide a working jsFiddle or similar